# AccessViolationException with Parallel.For()

Tags: c#, crash, task-parallel-library, parallel-extensions

The code snippet below exhibits a bug I was able to isolate from production code. The program will crash with a `System.AccessViolationException`.

My system configuration is Visual Studio 2013 on Windows 8.1 x64. To reproduce the bug, follow these steps in Visual Studio:

1. Create an empty Console Application
2. Replace the entire contents of Program.cs with the code below
3. Compile in **Release** mode, Any CPU
4. Start **without debugging** (CTRL + F5)

The program will crash immediately, displaying an error stack trace in the Console window.

I was not able to reduce the code any further, i.e. modifying any portion of the code will make the bug disappear.

Is there any way to tell the root cause of this bug? What would be a good workaround?

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ParallelBugTest
{
    class Program
    {
        private class Value
        {
            public double X;
        }

        private class Aggregator
        {
            private Value myval = new Value();

            public void Add()
            {
                // use Min() instead of Max() -> bug disappears
                myval.X = Math.Max(0, myval.X);
            }
        }

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Parallel.For(0, 10000, Process);
        }

        private static void Process(int k)
        {
            Value[] V = new Value[10000];
            Aggregator aggregator = new Aggregator();

            for (int i = 0; i < V.Length; i++)
            {
                V[i] = new Value();
                aggregator.Add();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting: `Parallel.For(0, 2000, Process);` crashes only sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

Everything in your code is thread-safe, since there is no shared state between threads (each iteration has its own `Aggregator` and the array of `Value`s and you're not using any `static` fields).

Even if your code wasn't thread-safe, it doesn't do anything unsafe (i.e. working directly with memory), which should be the only way to get `AccessViolationException`.

Because of that, I believe this is a bug in the CLR and you  should [report it](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Feedback) (click on the "submit feedback" link after logging in).

Comment: It is a Bug in combination with Multi-Threading as I could prove. So I don't call a buggy method Thread-Safe.

Comment: @MatthiasMüller What exactly is not thread-safe in [the implementation of `Math.Max()`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/math.cs#455)? Just because in this specific case, the bug appears only when you use `Math.Max()` with multithreading doesn't mean that `Math.Max()` is not thread-safe.

Answer (score -1):

Math.Max is not Thread-Safe. I guess Min is working because it is faster to calculate.
Locking the Max-Call works:

```
    private static Object lockObj = new Object();

    private class Value
    {
        public double X;
    }

    private class Aggregator
    {
        private Value myval = new Value();

        public void Add()
        {
            // use Min() instead of Max() -> bug disappears
            lock (lockObj)
            { 
                myval.X = Math.Max(0, myval.X);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Parallel.For(0, 10000, Process);
    }

    private static void Process(int k)
    {
        Value[] V = new Value[10000];
        Aggregator aggregator = new Aggregator();

        for (int i = 0; i < V.Length; i++)
        {
            V[i] = new Value();
            aggregator.Add();
        }
    }
```

Fast and easier way is just to use an ordinary iif:

```
        public void Add()
        {
            // use Min() instead of Max() -> bug disappears
            myval.X = myval.X > 0 ? myval.X : 0;
        }
```

Comment: I don't see how any `Math` members would not be thread-safe? The documentation of the `Math` class explicitly states: "Any public static members of this type are thread safe. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe."

Comment: With not Thread-Safe I meant it is a Bug in combination with Multi-Threading. As svick said, U might wanna report it. If u need a fast solution you can use the lock or you create your own Max-Method as shown in my post.